# How to know status of Kafka broker in java?

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-kafka

i am working on apache storm which has a topolgy main class. This topology contains the kafkaSpout which listen a kafka topic over a kafka broker. Now before i submit this topology i want to make sure the status of the kafka broker which has the topic. But i didnt found any way to do it? How a kafka brokers status can be known from storm tolopogy class ? Please help...

Comment: Did you find anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want a quick way to know if it is running or not you can just run the start command again with the same config:

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

If it's running then you should get an exception about the port already being in use.

Not foolproof, so better would be to use Zookeeper as mentioned above:

Personally I use intellij which has a Zookeeper plugin which helps you browse the brokers/topics running within it.  Probably something similar for Eclipse or other IDEs.

(IntelliJ)
Go to File > Settings > type zookeeper in the search, then install and click ok (may need to restart)
Go to File > Settings > type zookeeper in the search.  Click enable then put in the address where your zookeeper server is running and apply changes.  (Note you may need to check the port is correct too)

You should now see your zookeeper server as a tab on the left side of the IDE.
This should show you your broker and topics, consumers etc

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice one! In the later versions of intellij (mine 2016.2.3), use  File > Settings  >Other Settings > Zookeeper  to enable and add address of zookeeper server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured storm-ui, then that should give you a brief information about the running cluster, including informations such as currently running topologies, available free slots, supervisor info etc.

Programitically you can write a thrift client to retrieve those information from the storm cluster. You can possibly choose almost any language to develope your own client.
Check out [this](http://tutorials.github.io/pages/retrieving-storm-data-from-nimbus.html#.VOx8MvmUeSo) article for further reference

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of status you want to have, for most cases you would actually retrieve this from Zookeeper. In Zookeeper you can see registered brokers, topics and other useful things which might be what you're looking for.

Another solution would be to deploy a small regular consumer which would be able to perform those checks for you.

Comment: Like i just want to know whether the kafka broker to which i am listening from my kafka spout is in running state or not before i can run my storm topology class. This has to be done in java.

Comment: Then you should be able to do that with one of the suggestions above: checking if the broker is registered in Zookeeper or doing a test read with a java consumer.